# MYSQL/PHP query not giving the correct value

Tags: php, mysql

I have a textbox which pulls the maximum value from DB. But it gives wrong value.

Can you help figure out what went wrong here?

**basicInformation function:**

```
private function basicInformation() {
            // initialize variables
    $host = "localhost";
    $db_name = "test";
    $tbl_name = "ballpark_details";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";

    // connect to database
    mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
    mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB"); # ORDER BY ballpark_details_id DESC
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(ballpark_details_booking_ref) as max_booking_ref FROM `ballpark_details`");
    //Getting the max ref_id
    $values = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);    
    while ($query !=-1 && $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $max = $row['max_booking_ref'];
    }
    echo print_r($values, true);
    $html = "";
    $html .= '<fieldset id="basic-information" class="ui-widget">' . PHP_EOL;
    $html .= '<legend>Basic Ballpark Information</legend>' . PHP_EOL;
    $rowClass = "input-row";

    //$html .= $this->wrapLabelTextbox($this->inputBookingRef($values['max_booking_ref)']), $rowClass);
    $html .= $this->wrapLabelTextbox($this->inputBookingRef($max), $rowClass);
    //$html .= $this->wrapLabelTextbox($this->inputBookingRef(), $rowClass);
    $html .= $this->wrapLabelTextbox($this->inputBank(), $rowClass);
    $html .= $this->wrapLabelTextbox($this->inputRegion(), $rowClass);
    $html .= $this->wrapLabelTextbox($this->inputDescription(), $rowClass);
    $html .= $this->wrapLabelTextbox($this->inputNotes(), $rowClass);
    $html .= $this->wrapLabelTextbox($this->inputStartDate(), $rowClass);
    $html .= $this->wrapLabelTextbox($this->inputRequestedDeliveryDate(), $rowClass); #$this->inputEndDate()
    $html .= $this->wrapLabelTextbox($this->inputExpiryDate(), $rowClass);
    $html .= $this->wrapLabelTextbox($this->inputURL(), $rowClass);
    $html .= $this->wrapLabelTextbox($this->inputCAR(), $rowClass);
    (strcmp($_GET["page"], "createballpark"))?
        $html .= $this->wrapLabelTextbox($this->inputProjectStatusEdit(), $rowClass) :
        $html .= $this->wrapLabelTextbox($this->inputProjectStatusCreate(), $rowClass);         
    $html .= '</fieldset>';
    return $html;
}
```

**and my inputBookingRef function:**

```
private function inputBookingRef($values){ 
    //$values = $this->bookingRef;
    $html = "";
    $values++;
    $html .= '<label for="ref">Booking Ref: </label>';
    $html .= HTML::inputText("ref", 20, $values) . PHP_EOL;
    return $html;
}
```

**In this line:**

```
echo print_r($values, true);
```

It's displaying the last max value. But in my textbox it's just giving value number 1. I don't know what's wrong with my codings. Any help is greatly appreciated so I could go on with my program. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you call

```
mysql_fetch_assoc($query)
```

it will give you the next value of the result.
You have only 1 row from the query (if this is the real one).
The row value is assigned to the $values
and your WHILE loop should not be executed at all.

Leave only one of the statements and it should be fine  ;)

EDIT after comment:
also what is the purpose of
`$values++;` in the **inputBookingRef()** method

$values is probably of type string ..  ++ will make it something funny.

Comment: Hi commented out my while loop. I've tried this all over again but still the textbox gives me valuye number 1.

Comment: Yes I deleted a while ago $values++ in the inputBookingRef function, but when I did, there's no value in the textbox